# Looping through Arabic string and equivalent table glyph in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, arabic, lua-table

Translating the following code from Pascal to Lua, its purpose is -as Arabic script- forming a string in Arabic with ordered glyph types stored in tables to work with bitmap fonts.
 It works fine for strings with unique chars, e.g:the string("أحمد قطع الجزر") works fine, but a problem arises when a character is repeated, consider the three chars string("م ه م") formed as linked glyphs like this("مهم") returns the first glyph type for both (م)s (مهﻣ)instead of (مهم),the loop always gives first glyph type for repeated characters.
Here is the loop:

```
local current, nxt = ''

local linkBefore , linkAfter = false , false

function linkChars(text)

    linkBefore = false



    for i = 1 , utf8.len( text ) do

        current = utf8.sub(text , i , i ) 

        if i < utf8.len( text ) then

            nxt = utf8.sub( text , i+1 , i+1 )

        else

            nxt = ''

        end 

        linkAfter = (nxt > first and nxt < last) and (glyphTable[nxt].final or

            glyphTable[nxt].medial)

        if (current >= first and current <= last) and current ~= nxt then

            glyph= glyphTable[current]

            if (linkBefore and  linkAfter) and (glyph.medial) then

                text =string.gsub(text,current,glyph.medial) 

            elseif  linkAfter and (glyph.initial) then

                text =string.gsub( text , current , glyph.initial) 

            elseif linkBefore and( glyph.final )  then

                text =string.gsub( text , current , glyph.final)  

            elseif  glyph.isolated then

                text  =string.gsub( text , current , glyph.isolated) 

            end

            linkBefore = ( glyph.initial or glyph.medial ) and  linkAfter 

        else

            linkBefore = false

        end

    end

    text=text:gsub( "([\194-\244][\128-\191]*)" , string.reverse):reverse()

    return text

end
```

could what I'm doing wrong be that
 the (for) loop loops through all the chars for each condition when I have to to loop  conditions through each char?
however, how to make it work correctly?,

This is the full code:

```
    -- uses external utf8 file

    local utf8=require "utf8"

    --Arabic  glyphs table 

    local glyphTable= {}

    glyphTable= {

   {isolated=0xfe80},

    {isolated=0xfe81, final=0xfe82},

    {isolated=0xfe83, final=0xfe84},

    {isolated=0xfe85,final=0xfe86},

    {isolated=0xfe87,final=0xfe88}, 

--hemza teht ya

    {isolated=0xfe89,final=0xfe8a, initial=0xfe8b, medial=0xfe8c},

    {isolated=0xfe8d, final=0xfe8e},  

 --   alef

   {isolated=0xfe8f,final=0xfe90, initial=0xfe91, medial=0xfe92},  

   --ba 

    {isolated=0xfe93,final=0xfe94}, 

 --ta marbootah

    {isolated=0xfe95, final=0xfe96, initial=0xfe97, medial=0xfe98},  

 --ta

    {isolated=0xfe99,final=0xfe9a, initial=0xfe9b, medial=0xfe9c},

    --tha

    {isolated=0xfe9d,final=0xfe9e, initial=0xfe9f, medial=0xfea0},    

--jeem

    {isolated=0xfea1, final=0xfea2, initial=0xfea3, medial=0xfea4},  

      -- ha

    {isolated=0xfea5, final=0xfea6, initial=0xfea7, medial=0xfea8}, 

--kha

    {isolated=0xfea9,final=0xfeaa},  

    --dal
    {isolated=0xfeab,final=0xfeac},  

 --dhal
    {isolated=0xfead,final=0xfeae},


    --ra

    {isolated=0xfeaf,final=0xfeb0},  

 --za

    {isolated=0xfeb1,final=0xfeb2, initial=0xfeb3, medial=0xfeb4 }, 

      --seen

    {isolated=0xfeb5, final=0xfeb6, initial=0xfeb7, medial=0xfeb8},   

       --sheen

    {isolated=0xfeb9, final=0xfeba, initial=0xfebb, medial=0xfebc}, 

  --ssad

    {isolated=0xfebd, final=0xfebe, initial=0xfebf, medial=0xfec0},   

   --dhad

    {isolated=0xfec1,final=0xfec2, initial=0xfec3, medial=0xfec4},  


    --tda

    {isolated=0xfec5,final=0xfec6, initial=0xfec7, medial=0xfec8},    

 --thda

    {isolated=0xfec9, final=0xfeca, initial=0xfecb, medial=0xfecc}, 

  --ain

    {isolated=0xfecd, final=0xfece, initial=0xfecf, medial=0xfed0}, 

  --ghain

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {isolated=0xfed1, final=0xfed2, initial=0xfed3, medial=0xfed4}, 

   --fa

    {isolated=0xfed5, final=0xfed6, initial=0xfed7, medial=0xfed8}, 

   --gaf

    {isolated=0xfed9, final=0xfeda, initial=0xfedb, medial=0xfedc},

  --kaf

    {isolated=0xfedd,final=0xfede, initial=0xfedf, medial=0xfee0},  

--lam

    {isolated=0xfee1,final=0xfee2, initial=0xfee3,medial=0xfee4}, 

 --meem

    {isolated=0xfee5,final=0xfee6, initial=0xfee7,medial=0xfee8},

  --noon           

    {isolated=0xfee9,final=0xfeea, initial=0xfeeb, medial=0xfeec},

 --heh

    {isolated=0xfeed,final=0xfeee},  

  --wow

    {isolated=0xfeef, final=0xfef0},   

 --alef mongaleba  ya

    {isolated=0xfef1, final=0xfef2, initial=0xfef3,medial=0xfef4}, 

 --ya

    {isolated=0xfefb,final=0xfefc},

    {isolated=0x061f},

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {},

    {medial=0xfe7d}


  }

--renaming nested tables, each table takes the name for 
--its equivlent Arabic char

local n=1568

function renameKeys( )


 for k , v in ipairs(glyphTable) do

   if k <= (#glyphTable+1) then
    local c = ''
    n = n + 1
    c = utf8.char( n )
    glyphTable[c] = glyphTable[k]

    end

    end

    end

    function delOldKeys(  )

    for k, v in pairs(glyphTable) do
      if (type(k)) =="number" then
        glyphTable[k]=nil
    end

    end

    end

    function arabic.init()

    for k , v in pairs(glyphTable) do

    if glyphTable[k].isolated then

    glyphTable[k].isolated = utf8.char(glyphTable[k].isolated)

    end
    if glyphTable[k].initial then

    glyphTable[k].initial = utf8.char(glyphTable[k].initial)

    end

    if glyphTable[k].final then

    glyphTable[k].final = utf8.char(glyphTable[k].final)

    end

    if glyphTable[k].medial then

    glyphTable[k].medial = utf8.char(glyphTable[k].medial)

    end

    end

    renameKeys()

    delOldKeys()

    end





     local glyph={}

    local first , last =utf8.char(0x0620) , utf8.char(0x0651)



    local current , nxt = ''

    local linkBefore , linkAfter = false , false

   -- the main Arabic script function

    function linkChars(text)

    linkBefore = false

    for i= 1 , utf8.len( text ) do

     current = utf8.sub( text , i , i ) 

    if  i < utf8.len(text) then


      nxt =  utf8.sub( text , i+1 , i+1 ) 

      else

      nxt = ''

     end 

     linkAfter = ( nxt > first and nxt < last) and ( glyphTable[nxt].final 

    or glyphTable[nxt].medial )         


     if ( current> = first and current <= last ) and current ~= nxt then

        glyph = glyphTable[current]

    if ( linkBefore and  linkAfter ) and ( glyph.medial ) then

    text = string.gsub( text , current , glyph.medial ) 


    elseif  linkAfter and ( glyph.initial ) then

    text = string.gsub( text , current , glyph.initial ) 

    elseif linkBefore and( glyph.final )  then

    text = string.gsub(text , current , glyph.final)  

    elseif  glyph.isolated then

    text = string.gsub( text , current , glyph.isolated) 

    end

    linkBefore = ( glyph.initial or glyph.medial ) and  linkAfter

    else

    linkBefore = false

    end

    end

    text= text:gsub( "([\194-\244][\128-\191]*)" , string.reverse )

    return text

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

String to table has solved the problem, here:

```lua
function linkChars( s)


    local st=''

    local text = {}

    for i = 1, utf8.len(s) do

        text[i] = utf8.sub( s , i , i )
    end

     linkBefore = false

    for i=1,utf8.len(s) do

     current = utf8.sub(s,i,i()

    if i < utf8.len(s) then


      nxt = utf8.sub( s , i+1 , i+1 ) 

      else

      nxt =''

       end 

     linkAfter = ( nxt > first and nxt < last ) and ( glyphTable[nxt].final ~= ''
           or glyphTable[nxt].medial~='' ) and nxt~ = ''


     if ( current >= first and current <= last)  then

        glyph = glyphTable[current]

    if ( linkBefore and  linkAfter ) and ( glyph.medial ) then

    text[i] = glyph.medial

    elseif  linkAfter and (glyph.initial) then

    text[i] = glyph.initial

    elseif linkBefore and( glyph.final )  then

    text[i]=glyph.final

    elseif  glyph.isolated then

    text[i] = glyph.isolated 

    end


    linkBefore = (glyph.initial or glyph.medial ) and  linkAfter



    else

    linkBefore = false

    end

    end

     for k, v in ipairs(text) do
        st=st..v
    end

    return st:gsub("([\194-\244][\128-\191]*)", string.reverse):reverse()

    end
```